# Instantiate a service according to a property on Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

A good practice is defining a service as an interface and its implementation on a class.

Assuming I have 2 classes which implement the same interface, and I'd like to differentiate them according a property (not to a profile). I mean, if I have `@Autowire private MyServiceInterface myService;` I'd like to receive an instance of `PotatoServiceImpl` if I have `myproperty=potato` or an instance of `TomatoServiceImpl` if I have `myproperty=tomato`.

I'm not using profiles.

P.S. When I say a property,I mean a property in `application.properties`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look:

```
public interface MyInterface {
}

@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "myproperty" havingValue = "potato", matchIfMissing = false)
public class MyPotatoImpl implements MyInterface {
}

@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "myproperty" havingValue = "tomato", matchIfMissing = false)
public class MyTomatoImpl implements Myinterface {
}

@Component
public class Consumer {
    @Autowire
    private MyInterface tomatoOrPotato; //depending on property myproperty value
}
```

This is for me a very elegant solution to implement the strategy creational design pattern spring styled.
Look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) for docs about `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation.

Comment: I worked,I just would like to remark that rather than using `prefix` you have to use `name`.

Comment: Yes you're right. When you have a property composed by multiple parts dots separated such as `mySection.coolProperty` you can you specify `prefix` attribute as `mySection` and `name` as `coolProperty`.